# Heroku scheduler weekly?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, ruby-on-rails-4

How can I get the heroku scheduler to run weekly?

Is this even possible, from what I can see I can only schedule hourly, every 10 mins, or daily tasks with no option for a weekly.

If not, what are other Heroku Add-ons that might allow me to run jobs (i.e. cron job) tasks on a weekly bassis in production.

Thanks!

**Update 2:**

```
  require 'date'
task :weeklydelete do
  if Date.today.wday.zero?
    runner "Event.clear_expired"
    runner "Activity.clear_expired"
  end
end
```

**Update 2.5:**

```
$heroku run bundle exec rake weeklydelete -a friendiosenew
Running `bundle exec rake weeklydelete` attached to terminal... up, run.6194
rake aborted!
undefined local variable or method `path' for main:Object
/app/lib/tasks/weeklydelete.rake:2:in `block in <top (required)>'
Tasks: TOP => weeklydelete
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Answer (score 29):

I found a great answer [here](https://blog.dbrgn.ch/2013/10/4/heroku-schedule-weekly-monthly-tasks/). Just use a bash script in the Heroku Scheduler that checks the day of the week before running your command:

```
if [ "$(date +%u)" = 1 ]; then MY_COMMAND; fi   # only run on Mondays
```

Comment: Would I just copy-paste your bash script in the Heroku Scheduler line to make it work? or would I have to create a bash script?

Comment: This is brilliant, the best solution to this question. You can just use that line straight off @NishantRoy

Comment: What do I substitute for MY_COMMAND.  for example, my procfile for my dyno is worker: scrapy crawl main

Answer (score 10):

Set up a daily job, and in the job check if the day of week is Sunday (or whichever day). If it is that day, run the job. If it isn't that day, do nothing and exit.

edit: I was thinking more like

```
require 'date'
task :weeklydelete do
  if Date.today.wday.zero?
    runner "Event.clear_expired"
    runner "Activity.clear_expired"
  end
end
```

The logging to a file stuff wont work on heroku, and I'm not sure what you're using for the time stuff, but I fear if scheduler runs it not exactly at 3, that stuff might not work.

Comment: Thanks! I've updated the post with the code, let me know if it looks O.K to you. Cheers.

Comment: Perfect will try this now, thanks! And will this be running every sunday - or daily? I'd only like it to execute Sundays to avoid over-usage with Herokus Dynos.

Comment: It will run every day, but on non Sunday days it will exit almost immediately, and at most be running for only a few seconds on non-sundays.

Comment: Got it - that's cool and essentially how I wanted it! Unfortunately I'm getting an error when I run 'heroku run bundle exec rake weeklydelete'. I've updated the original post. What's going wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

the Date class has some really great helper methods. So, `Date.today.wday.zero?` could be shortened to `Date.today.sunday?`

Answer (score 0):

The idea above about running a daily job but then having it exit without running if the day of the week isn't the day you want the job to run is a great solution. However, if you have a worker dyno running Sidekiq or DelayedJob (or any other queueing scheme that allows scheduled jobs), there's another solution, which is to seed the jobs queue with jobs that are not to be run until the day of the week you need.

This approach is a bit cleaner than checking for a particular day of the week, but it only makes sense if you are already using at least one background worker dyno and/or price sensitivity is not an issue.